# WSO2 AS + Developer Studio + maven project

Tags: maven-3, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I'm figuring out how to develop a JAX-RS service with WSO2 Developer Studio (2.1.0) and deploy it to a WSO2 AS 5.0.1 server.

When I create a new CAR project containing a JAX-RS Service project I can start and deploy the CAR on the running WSO2 AS 5.0.1 service right from Eclipse.

However, as I install the m2eclipse plugin and include maven-dependencies in the project these dependencies are not on the classpath of the deployed WAR module.

What is the recommended way to handle maven dependencies in a JAX-RS project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the maven dependencies you declare in pom.xml are not added to the classpath of the Developer Studio projects and vice-versa. We will fix this issue in a future Developer Studio version.

As a workaround for the moment, you need to add the dependencies to the project classpath manually.

Comment: This is now fixed in Developer Studio 3.0.0. You can sync the Eclipse Project dependencies to pom.xml and you can also sync the Maven dependencies with Eclipse projecct with mvn eclipse:eclipse now.